# recv call returns 0 vs POLLHUP event in C poll

Tags: c, sockets, poll-syscall

(In C socket programming, using `poll` to manage the fd's and its events)
With a data stream socket returned from an `accept()` call, what's the difference between the event POLLHUP and getting 0 when calling recv(fd, ...) ? They both seem to indicate the connection was closed from the other end, but I wanted to know if there is any technical difference between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`POLLHUP` in the `revents` of a `struct pollfd` tells you if the other end of a pipe or socket has been closed. That means you can't write to the descriptor (If it's open for writing) without getting a `SIGPIPE`, but there might still be data pending waiting to be read (If it's open for reading). Once all remaining bytes have been read, then functions like `recv(2)` and `read(2)` will return 0.

Both `POLLIN` and `POLLHUP` can thus be set at the same time, but not `POLLOUT` and `POLLHUP` - those two are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I see. So I should add to events POLLIN and POLLHUP and when POLLHUP is registered, call recv if theres data left until I get a 0 return value ? I was previously just handling POLLIN with recv = 0 as a closed connection.

Comment: @carce-bo `POLLHUP` has no meaning when in `events`; it's explicitly ignored, just like `POLLERR`. But basically yes.